# Tensorflow can't find user_ops after replacing it

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-import

Currently I am trying to get an existing model from a colleague to work in TensorFlow in a Docker environment. One step in the process is to replace the TensorFlow [user_ops file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/user_ops/user_ops.py) with a custom version. However when I try to import TensorFlow after this replacement I get the following error:

```
>>> import tensorflow
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.user_ops import user_ops
ImportError: No module named user_ops
```

However when I exit python and try:

```
less /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/user_ops/user_ops.py
```

I get the user_ops file I intend to import in python. So the module appears to be there, in contrast to what the error claims. Can anyone help me find what the problem might be?

edit:
on request:

```
>python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

and:

```
>python -c 'import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__file__)' 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.user_ops import user_ops
ImportError: No module named user_ops
```

Comment: What does `python --version` give also, `python -c 'import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__file__)`?

Comment: Thanks, added results in the post

Comment: Yeah, that second one was a stupid idea on my part. You can delete that part if you want.

Comment: No problem, I'll leave it up just in case. It shows the standard questions have been asked

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

I replaced the user_ops file by replacing the entire user_ops folder. However the folder I was given didn't contain a **init**.py file. This was apparently crucial: adding an empty version of this file into my user_ops folder solved the issue.